# Is there a linux command that shows string of specified length in a file?

Tags: linux, string, shell, file

I need a linux command that print on shell all string of specified length contained in a specific file.

Comment: How are those strings delimited?

Comment: For examples I have a file containing names: name1, name2...nameN all of them are on a different line so I have to print on command line all of these names that are of 6 character

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
grep '^.\{6\}$' file
sed '/^.\{6\}$/!d' file
sed -n '/^.\{6\}$/p' file
awk -F '' 'NF==6' file
```

They all print lines of 6 char length from `file`.

Comment: @oguzismail : Why do you have to escape the braces? You are within single quotes anyway.

Comment: @user1934428 `{, }, (, ), +, ?` must be escaped in basic regular expressions

Comment: I see! Hence, you could also write `grep -E '^.{6}$' file`, right?

Comment: @user1934428 yeah. I always prefer what is default, it's just a matter of choice.

Answer (score 0):

Having one name on each line as you commented, and looking for a 6 chars length:

```sh
awk '{ if (length($0) == 6) print }' input_file > output_file
```

Will leave 6 char long names in `output_file`